# Using Group By Having in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help me to convert the below query to LINQ with Lambda expression.

```sql
select idshiftschedule,Date from Teammateassignments 
where IdClinic = 19
group by IdshiftSchedule,DATE having COUNT(Date)>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a filter on the groups afterwards:

```
 var results = from item in assignments
               where item.IdClient == 19
               group item by new { item.IdShiftSchedule, item.Date } into g
               where g.Count() > 1
               select g.Key;
```

(I'm assuming that `Count(Date) > 1` is really just counting the number of items in the group... it's not clear to me what it would do if `Date` is nullable, for example.)

Comment: Thanks Jon for help. I have written this query using Lambda expression.but  its not working properly.Can u tell me what is wrong with this. Assignments.Where(tma =>tma.ClinicId == tmShift.ClinicId
                                                                       ).Select(t => t)                                                                       .GroupBy(s => s.ShiftId, s => s.Date)                                                                  .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)                                                                    .ToList()

Comment: Yeah U r right Jon,Count(Date) > 1 is counting the items in the group.In my case Date never be null. It is a not null column

Comment: @sid: Your `GroupBy` should be `GroupBy(s => new { s.ShiftId, s.Date })`.